# Function doesn't stop after first result - Prolog

Tags: prolog

I don't understand why the function doesn't stop after first result in this:

```
getNo(A, [[A,X]|_], X).
getNo(A, [_|Tail], X):- 
    getNo(A, Tail, X), !.
getNo(_,[],0).
```

And example inputs:

```
?- getNo(a,[[a,2],[b,1]],X).
X = 2 ;
X = 0.

?- getNo(b,[[a,2],[b,1]],X).
X = 1.

?- getNo(c,[[a,2],[b,1]],X).
X = 0.
```

The full stop works when the element is not the first in the array. But why doesn't it stop for the first element in array. Why does it give two answers for 'a' in the example input.

I think it is the last line which causes it, but I can't put a full stop there "!." or can't come up with any other way to solve this.

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, the exclamation mark is the cut operator, and it does *not* behave as a "full stop." It simply commits you to the choices that have been made until it is run. By tracing we can see that it is really not relevant to the problem you're having:

```
?- getNo(a,[[a,2],[b,1]],X).
X = 2 ; [trace]
   Redo: (6) getNo(a, [[a, 2], [b, 1]], _G221) ? creep
   Call: (7) getNo(a, [[b, 1]], _G221) ? creep
   Call: (8) getNo(a, [], _G221) ? creep
   Exit: (8) getNo(a, [], 0) ? creep
   Exit: (7) getNo(a, [[b, 1]], 0) ? creep
   Exit: (6) getNo(a, [[a, 2], [b, 1]], 0) ? creep
X = 0.
```

So you can see here that `getNo(a, [], 0)` is also going to succeed. And it does on its own too, because there's nothing to stop it:

```
?- getNo(a,[],X).
X = 0.
```

There's no reason to expect that it could distinguish between the case when it has arrived at an empty list by a recursive invocation or by a direct call simply by using the cut. I think you'll have to restructure your predicate to get the behavior you want. For instance:

```
get_number(A, [[A,X]|_], X).
get_number(A, [_|Tail],  X)  :- get_number(A, Tail, X).

getNo(A, L, X) :- get_number(A, L, X), !.
getNo(_, _, 0).
```

As a parenthetical remark about using Prolog, it often happens that you do need to create another predicate. Don't be afraid to create helper predicates. Among other things, there's no other way to really deal with loops that need their initial conditions set up or post-processing. In other languages you can completely insulate all the work you need to do behind the interface of a single function, but in Prolog that often simply isn't possible and you will have to delegate to a helper.

Comment: That solves the problem indeed. Thank you for that. Took me a little bit to understand why getNo(b, [], 0) wasn't an option. But after comparing my code and Yours, I now understand why. Thank you!

Comment: @ArturKäpp No problem. :) Please do see the paragraph I just added at the bottom, which may speak to the same realization.